# ¿Cómo hacer un UPDATE en una consulta que está condicionada por un WHERE y a su vez por un limitada por LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito ayuda con un límite de consulta. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es actualizar una tabla de Alumnos para que a cada uno se le asigne automáticamente una sección de acuerdo con un límite establecido por el usuario administrador.

Ya eh intentado usar la funcion between pero e fracasado!

// ASI NO FUNCIONA

```
$consulta = "UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'A' 
WHERE `EtapaGradoGrupo` = '5° Año' LIMIT 20,15; ";
```

// ASI SI FUNCIONA pero actualiza todos los registro del 1 al 20 y quiero que comience a actualizar desde el registro 15 hasta el registro 20 es decir solo 5 no los 20

```
$consulta = "UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'A' 
WHERE `EtapaGradoGrupo` = '5° Año' LIMIT 20;";
```

Me gustaría que Cada estudiante de un "N° Año" en concreto actualizara su sección a "A", "B", "C" ... Pero que en la consulta seleccione Solo los alumnos de dicho "N° Año" Limitados Por la cantidad de alumnos por seccion que selecciono el usuario Nota: La consulta funciona solo Cuando el limit tiene un solo parámetro pero cuando añado el segundo parámetro para que incluya la posición desde la cual empezara a actualizar la sección este me da error IMG con el error de que me da MySql

---

Intente hacer lo siguiente NOTA: Estoy aprendiendo a usar StackOverflow

```
require("datos_de_conexion.php");
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $direccion , $usuario , $password ,$servidor);
mysqli_set_charset($conexion ,"utf8");

$consulta = "SELECT*FROM`estudiantes`WHERE`Etapa/Grado/Grupo`='5°Año'LIMIT 
5, 5";
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion , $consulta );

while( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ){

$IDE = $fila["ExpedienteN°"];

$Actualizar = "UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE 
`ExpedienteN°` = $IDE;";
$resultado_2 = mysqli_query( $conexion , $Actualizar );

}

echo "Fueron afectadas " . $filasAfectadas = mysqli_affected_rows( $conexion 
);
```

*Genera la consulta perfectamente PEROOO cuando ejecuto la consulta dentro del while solo afecta a 1 fila es decir el ciclo debería hacer 5 vueltas pero solo hace 1 si imprimo en pantalla esto es lo que aparece:

```
UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE `ExpedienteN°` = 6; 
UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE `ExpedienteN°` = 7; 
UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE `ExpedienteN°` = 8; 
UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE `ExpedienteN°` = 9; 
UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'Z' WHERE `ExpedienteN°` = 10; 
Fueron afectadas -1
```

Como vez se generan las consultas correctamente en cada ciclo pero solo se ejecuta la primera con ID = 6!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pudieras probar con el uso de `BETWEEN` el cual funciona para:

> Realizar tu actualización con los registros de un intervalo de datos en específico, en este caso todos los `id` que comienzan desde el 15 hasta el 20.

Así:

```
$consulta = "UPDATE `estudiantes` SET `seccion` = 'A' 
             WHERE `EtapaGradoGrupo` = '5° Año' 
             AND id BETWEEN 15 AND 20";
```

Si ahora haces:

```
SELECT * FROM estudiantes 
LIMIT 14, 20;
```

*Te va a mostrar todos los registros del 15 al 20 con los valores actualizados con la columna `seccion` actualizada.*

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentare! :)

Comment: Gracias Amigo, Pero me genera el mismo error!

Comment: que raro yo ya lo probé en un grupo de datos y funciona @DavidAlvarado, seguro lo pusiste como lo coloqué?

Comment: Cuando colocas "id"  antes del BETWEEN te refieres al nombre de la columna autoincrementable de la tabla "estudiantes"?

Comment: Si @DavidAlvarado sería la opción para encontrar los registros desde el 15 al 20, es decir en ese intervalo de datos

Comment: Por favor @DavidAlvarado si ocupas hacer aclaraciones puedes dejar un comentario o editar y ampliar tu pregunta, pero no editar mi respuesta para exponer tus dudas ahí pues eso no es correcto

Comment: Disculpa amigo, no se utilizar bien StackOverflow :) Por ayuda!

Comment: Ya FUNCIONOOOOOO Muchas Gracias, Te juro que esta mañana el Between no funcionaba!